# oversampled coefficient for existing exponential smoothing

Tags: sampling, smoothing

Say I have an exponential smoothing for certain $\Delta t$, $t_{i+1} = t_i + \Delta t$. In this sampling, I choose a particular $\alpha$ to *filter* signal $z_i$ like
$$
v_1 = z_0 \\
v_{i+1} = \alpha\:z_i + (1-\alpha)\:v_i  
$$

and we have some sort of agreement as to what $\alpha$ to use.

Now, someone comes along and tells me that I am able to get, say, five times more samples in the same $\Delta t$ period. I need to modify the smoothing factor $\alpha$. It seems to me, intuitively, that the new factor, say $\alpha'$, that has the same *discount effect* for previous values but with five times more *iterations* should be
$$
(1-\alpha')^5 = 1-\alpha
$$

**Is this correct? Is there any principled approaches to justify this?**

Note: The formula above seems sensible in the sense that the original *asymptotic* variance (for a constant model) 
$$
\mathbb{V}ar[v] \to \frac{\alpha}{2-\alpha} \sigma^2
$$
becomes
$$
\mathbb{V}ar[v'] \to \frac{\alpha'}{2-\alpha'} \sigma^2
$$
which, under the equation above, is actually smaller (I checked this). This makes sense as more data would give more precision for $v_t$ as *estimator* of a constant $z_t = k + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's instructive to take a look at the impulse responses, taking absolute time into account. I'm assuming the following recursion:

$$y_n=\alpha x_n+(1-\alpha)y_{n-1}\tag{1}$$

The impulse response corresponding to the recursive system described by (1) is

$$h_n=\alpha(1-\alpha)^n$$

Assume now that we have a discrete-time system with sample interval $T$, and another one with sample interval $T^{\prime}=T/L$. Let $\beta=1-\alpha$, and let $\alpha^{\prime}$ and $\beta^{\prime}$ be the constants of the system with sample interval $T^{\prime}$. In order for the two systems to have the same time constant and the same scaling we require (considering a point in time $t_n=nT=nLT^{\prime}$)

$$\alpha\beta^{n}=\alpha^{\prime}{\beta^{\prime}}^{nL}\tag{2}$$

From (2) we see that

$$\alpha=\alpha^{\prime},\quad \beta=\beta^{\prime L}\quad
\text{(i.e. $\beta^{\prime}\neq 1-\alpha^{\prime}$)}$$

In this case the impulse response of the system with the higher sampling rate is simply an interpolated version of the other system's impulse response. Note that the condition on $\beta^{\prime}$ is the one that you came up with intuitively, and it is also the more important of the two because it affects the time constant of the system. The choice $\alpha=\alpha^{\prime}$ only affects the scaling and in this sense is secondary. Choosing $\alpha^{\prime}=1-\beta^{\prime}$ is of course also possible and just changes the scaling.

Comment: View at the impulse response, great idea!

Comment: What does it mean to say that setting $\alpha^{\prime}$ to $1 - \beta^{\prime}$ "only affects the scaling"?  How will the system behave if the $\alpha^{\prime}$ value is changed to no longer equal $\alpha$?

Comment: Intuitively, it seems to me that I _must_ use $\alpha^{\prime} = 1 - \beta^{\prime}$.  Exponential smoothing computes the current smoothed value as the _weighted sum_ of the current data value and the previous smoothed value.  If $\alpha^{\prime}$ is anything _other_ than $1 - \beta^{\prime}$,then the sum of the weights would not be equal to $1$, and it wouldn't be "exponential smoothing".